# Performance: navigation prop. vs sql query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Consider we have `class Project` with many `Sprints`.

The `Project` has `ICollection<Sprints>`.
I want to select and paginate these `Sprints` and return to user from a Web application.

I can select **this way** : `project.Sprints.Skip(...).Take(...)`
***or***
**this way** `sprints.Where(x=>x.ProjectId == some_projectId).Skip(...).Take(...)`.

I want to understand performance difference between selecting and paginating  `ICollection<T>` as navigation property and as `IQueryable`.

The **first** way i think will be not good besause all `Sprints` are iterated in memory
The **second** way can be slower if there are many-many `Sprints` on the table (and also it looks less obvious).

But how do You think?

P.S. I am using entity framework 6.0.1 codefirst.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one big difference. When you are using navigation property, all related entities will be loaded when you'll try to access that property

```
project.Sprints.Skip(...).Take(...)
```

So, here all sprints are loaded in a single query, and pagination will occur in memory. Taking next pages will query in-memory sprints collection which project holds. Database will not be hit anymore. But with your second approach

```
sprints.Where(x => x.ProjectId == some_projectId).Skip(...).Take(...)
```

pagination will occur on server side, and you will hit database each time when loading next page.

Which approach to choose depends on total count of sprints, amount of data you need to download, and sprints per page. Also it depends on type of application you are building. If it is web application and you cannot store `project` object between requests, then server-side pagination (second option) is your choice. If your `Sprint` is light-weight object and amount of these objects is not huge, then downloading all at once make sense. There is no solution which fits all cases.

Comment: thanks, now i have no doubts on what to choose (2nd way)